# Debugging Information

Tags: debugging, logging

I have a windows service that runs in the background and transfers files from one database to another, and i was wondering what the best way to log/store information about this service so i can debug it in the event of a failure. Currently I'm just using nlog to output exception text and status lines, but is there any information that is usually included in log files?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to write to the [Windows Event EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

Comment: I have a problem writing to the event log because on a production server unneeded entries in the event log can obscure problems, so i an definitely using a text/xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can include whatever is helpful to you to figure out what has gone wrong.  I like to log to the Event Logs but I see a lot of people choosing to log to databases and xml/text files.  I am working on a project where I work that is very large and developed over many iterations and expansions and changed hands several times now.  Logging is a mess IMHO because each module logs to its own location in a different format and a very few actually use the event logs (the only ones we can reliable get debugging information from when something goes wrong).  Give yourself a way to turn logging up and down  so you can log more information sometimes and less others without recompiling.  We use a logging level attribute in the config file and based on that we decide what to log and what not.